# Cannot get correct mySQL records from today until tomorrow

Tags: php, mysql

Probably it is asked many times but I have a table with some records. Some with tomorrow's date and some with the day after tomorrow. I try the following

```
SELECT * FROM Games where GAMEID='".$id."' AND GAMEDATE >=CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

And I get records with dates 10/1/2017 and 11/1/2017. Shouldn't INTERVAL 1 DAY get only the dates of 10/1/2017?

If I use

```
GAMEDATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND GAMEDATE <= CURDATE()
```

I get empty query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the records only from tomorrow

try this query

```
select * from Games where GAMEDATE between curdate() + interval 1 day 
and 
curdate() + interval 2 day and GAMEID='".$id."';
```

check demo table

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8f65/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use addition like that. You need to use `DATE_ADD()`:

```
GAMEDATE >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

If you want to go backwards, you will use `DATE_SUB`.

Comment: Again I get records together with 11/01/2017 and not only 10/01/2017

Comment: When you say "10/01/2017" are you meaning October 1, 2017 or January 10, 2017?

Comment: Today is the 9th (at least here in EST) -- so either of those would be greater than or equal, as expected. Check the timezone of your server. If it is the 10th for you, your mysql server might think it is the 9th right now.

Comment: Here in Greece is still 01/09/2017 thats why I expect 01/10/2017 and not 01/11

Comment: The query is `>=` meaning it matches the 10th and also ANYTHING after that date (including the 11th). If you only want the 10th, then you need to just use `=` without the greater than.

Comment: I tested it and without = and still the same

Comment: without > I dont get anything